# Project is out of date, visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installshield

I am using visual studio 2012. when I was starting to create a setup file using the "**Install shield**" , but i got an issue `project is out of date`. I did search on Google, MSDN for this but i didn't find the proper answer to fix it. 
when i build it although, it shows error during building as

```
Error   3   -3204: Cannot extract icon with index 0 from file C:\Users\Own\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyRibbonAddIn\MyRibbonAddIn\obj\Debug\MyRibbonAddIn.dll.   ISEXP : error : -3204: Cannot extract icon with index 0 from file C:\Users\Own\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyRibbonAddIn\MyRibbonAddIn\obj\Debug\MyRibbonAddIn.dll.
```

I added the icon too but it didn't found that icon. what should i do to resolve this problems.

Comment: Do you know which project is out of date? Did you upgrade the solution from an earlier version of Visual Studio?

Comment: There is only one project in the solution. i haven't upgraded it, its new installation of VS-2012.

Comment: What is the project in your solution, the `Install Shield` project or the `MyRibbonAddIn.dll` project?

Comment: `MyRibbonAddIn.dll` is my project , install shield is the tool i am using for making the setup file.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Solution:**

> At the time of Installation Wizard, while missing the reselection of
>   the Image / Icon for shortcut after we have browsed the resource path.
>   Missing this causes this index error (please refer screenshot). after
>   re-sele[image]ction rebuild is required this solves problem.